# How do I POST data to an IIS 6 server

Tags: java, http, silverlight, iis

I am working in a corporate environment and we use a program that is very slow to display information about our clients. The application is based off Silverlight. I have been using Firefox Dev console to try and get as much information about the application as I can. Here is what I have so far when I use the Silverlight application

```
Request URL: http://<Host>/dashboard/DataService.svc
Request Method: Post

<Request Headers>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host:<Host>
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: NTLM <Token>
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

<Request Body>
Referer:http://<Host>/dashboard/ClientBin/<Company Name>.Dashboard.UI.xap?dt=-2052067764 Content-Length: 186 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IDataService/FindStoresByStoreNum" <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><FindStoresByStoreNum xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><value>8464</value></FindStoresByStoreNum></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I am trying to send the same request in Java. The problem is the IIS server uses NTLMv2 to authenticate (so we can use our Active Directory accounts to sign in), and then I think it uses SOAP to send the data through?

Okay so I was poking around, and I found a WSDL xml file

Everytime I run it I get an error 411 if I change the data I get 415
What do I need to do in order to request data on the server?

```
<wsdl:definitions name="DataService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService_policy">        
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <http:NegotiateAuthentication/>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://<Host>/Dashboard/DataService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/><xsd:import schemaLocation="http://<Host>/Dashboard/DataService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://<Host>/Dashboard/DataService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/_Dashboard_Dal"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://<Host>/Dashboard/DataService.svc?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Linq"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://<Host>/Dashboard/DataService.svc?xsd=xsd4" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://<Host>/Dashboard/DataService.svc?xsd=xsd5" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dashboard.Service"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://<Host>/Dashboard/DataService.svc?xsd=xsd6" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.SqlClient"/>

        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="IDataService_GetScheduledStoreCountByProject_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetScheduledStoreCountByProject"/>
    </wsdl:message>
```

My question now is how do I use this dataservice in java?

Comment: HTTP 411 is a bad content-length and you have: `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", );` ?

Comment: @AlexK. Hey I updated the question, Sorry about the messy code